# Add breakpoint in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I must be doing something stupidly wrong as I just cannot seem to add breakpoints in Visual Studio Code.

The following pops up when I right click on my code. (left clicking beside the line numbers didn't work either)

[image]

I've read the documentation here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints

It states:

> Breakpoints can be toggled by clicking on the editor margin.

I have no idea what it is or where I find it. To say the least the documentation for beginners is lacking.

Comment: Click to the left of the numbers

Comment: F9 may be a keyboard shortcut too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Visual Studio Code is buggy.

I couldn't left click beside the line numbers, however.. It started to work when I went to debug view and started playing about with all of the boxes seen below, it must of activated something:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is no breakpoint marker on the left margin of line 70 in app.js?

Comment: @Filburt I added that after it started working :) Before I fiddled with the box in the image, left-clicking resulted in nothing happening. Probably a minor bug in the code.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue with VS Code v1.17.2. Interesting is that when I type 'debugger' VSC will break on that line but still I cannot set breakpoints with F9 or mouse click before line numbers. @Karl: what you did exactly to make setting breakpoints work again?

Comment: It turned out that in html files I cannot set breakpoints inside <script> tags but in pure js files I can.

Answer (score 141):

Go to [VS->Settings->Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhC2Y.png) and change "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere" to true.

Comment: I am pretty sure i didn't have to do that when i installed vs code before...

Answer (score 30):

I also ran into this issue. Make sure you don't have

```
"editor.glyphMargin": false,
```

in your user or workspace settings.

Answer (score 24):

Updated Answer as of **December 2020**

For those who have trouble in finding the debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere.

File->Preference->Settings

Then search 'debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere'. Click the Checkbox then it will automatically save. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: This setting changed to false when I updated to VSCode version 1.52.0.

Comment: After an update, this setting was turned off, I don't understand why this is done.

Comment: This answer was very helpful.  I couldn't find the settings.

Answer (score 8):

The editor margin is left to the line numbers.

Left-clicking there should set a breakpoint on the desired line.

Comment: Been using this for years, and now adding breakpoints to the left of the number area disappeared. Using VS Code 1.52.0.